# WooCommerce widget - List of orders from date to date

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to create a dashboard widget to show orders for the first half of the current month, this is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'register_my_dashboard_widget' );
function register_my_dashboard_widget() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
    'my_dashboard_widget',
    'Ordiers',
    'my_dashboard_widget_display'
 );

}

function my_dashboard_widget_display() {
global $wpdb;

$date_from = '2016-09-01';
$date_to = '2016-09-15';
$post_status = implode("','", array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed') );

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
        WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND post_date BETWEEN '{$date_from}  00:00:00' AND '{$date_to} 23:59:59'
    ");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
}
```

How can I give a list style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a list style you need to Iterate each order in a loop. You will echo **`<ul>`** HTML tags outside the loop and **`<li>`** HTML tags inside the loop. I have add in your query the desired order status.

I have changed a little bit your code:

```
function my_dashboard_widget_display() {
    global $wpdb;

    $date_from = '2016-09-01';
    $date_to = '2016-09-15';

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND post_status = 'wc-completed' OR post_status = 'wc-processing'
        AND post_date BETWEEN '{$date_from}  00:00:00' AND '{$date_to} 23:59:59'
    " );

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($result as $value) {

        // Getting WC order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $value->ID );

        // For example displaying order number and status
        echo '<li>Order #'.$order->id. ' with status ' . $order->get_status() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested annd works

Comment: You have missing brackets I think. it should be *(post_status = 'wc-completed' OR post_status = 'wc-processing')*  (note the brackets! otherwise the query might not deliver the expected results)